# how to get name of column(s) causing error "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition" 

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to insert data from one table into another. Both tables have about 100 columns. 
They don't have the same structure, but "almost": the source table has about 20 columns fewer- some of them are NOT NULL. For those columns, I have to define a default, of course.

My first trial resulted in an error message (surprise surprise):

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

But in my complex case, this message is not really helpful. Is there a way to get a more precise error message?

Comment: 100 cols? Sounds like a pita to work with.

Comment: Unfortunately: no, I'm afraid - SQL Server doesn't tell you much more than this :-(

Comment: Have you source columns and destination columns side by side to have a look to where's the mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest making your query easier to read, rather than relying on the error message from the RDBMS. One thought:

- Put each column on its own line.

```
 INSERT INTO TargetTable (
    Col1,
    Col2,
    ....
 )
 SELECT 
    Col1,
    Col2,
    ....
 FROM SourceTable
```

- create a new Excel sheet.
- In SQL Server Management Studio, Alt-F1 your TargetTable; copy-paste the Column_name (and perhaps the Nullable values) into Excel sheet's ColumnA.
- Copy/paste the TargetTable columns into ColumnB.
- Run a macro or visually inspect/adjust the differences. The nullables you mention, you'll have to know offhand.